# Very slow connection on some websites using VPN

Tags: vpn, performance, softether, ssl-vpn

Some websites like YouTube are filtered in my country. I create a VPN using two servers, one in my country and one in Germany. I'm using cascading and a tunnel is performed from Germany to my county.

There is a problem: All websites that are filtered in my country open with extremely high speed but websites that are not filtered are very slow and sometimes I get a timeout.

Does anyone have an idea?